# Mail.To.Add(TextBox1.Text) ' кому vb.net выдает ошибку

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim email As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\S+@\S+\.\S+")
    ...
    Mail.To.Add(TextBox1.Text) ' кому
```

если `kshyms@yandex@gmail.com` 1 адрес и 2 адрес `kshyms@yahoo.com` нет ошибки письмо отправляется vb.net 
если `988811@mail.ru`  3 адрес выдает ошибку Необработанное исключение типа `"System.FormatException"` произошло в `System.dll`

Дополнительные сведения: Недопустимый знак в заголовке электронной почты: ' '.

В цикле отправляю на адреса письма и эта проблема и как её решить?

Comment: Переформулируй вопрос. Что-то ничего непонятно

Comment: что за данные разбирает регулярка? `Mail.To.Add(TextBox1.Text)` - здесь `email` не используется, может действительно в текстовом поле `TextBox1.Text` передается пробельный символ?